# Java Android empty StringBuilder toString() returns [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@405a3c98

Tags: java, android, debugging, stringbuilder

I am using a StringBuilder as shown below. When there is some value everything is ok. But sometimes no values are appended, so i am expecting empty as result. But when I check the value of result in the eclipse adt latest version , i see a strange string value like [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@405a3c98 having length 39.

Any ideas? Is this normal? Should I put a if condition to avoid this situation, that is , if length is 0 than return empty string ?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

    ...
    ...
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(instream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
String result = builder.toString();
```

Just after 2 hours , i saw the code below :(). Thanks guys:)

```
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getStackTrace().toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getStackTrace().toString();
        }

        return builder.toString();
```

Comment: Euh...Where's your output statement? That's not the result of `builder.toString()`.

Comment: Sometimes it is good just to ask others :) thx

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It could be if you did `builder.append(stackTraceElement.toString());`.